# Skype, green screen, no microphone

Tags: skype, webcam, microphone

I have issues with skype using my brand new System 76 Galago Ultrapro, running Ubuntu 13.04.

I installed Skype through ubuntu software centre (after allowing Canonical partner stuff), but it won't work, the video is a green screen, and it won't connect to the microphone. The webcam works when using Cheese, and the microphone appears to work in general (it shows sound levels when I go to the Input tab under the Sound settings).

I tried to fix the green screen issue using this command:

$ echo -e '#!bin/bash n LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype' | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/skype sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/skype

as suggested here: http://debianhelp.wordpress.com/2012/09/28/to-do-list-after-installing-ubuntu-13-04-aka-raring-ringtail-operating-system/

but no luck. Any ideas?

I have also asked this question to the System 76 tech support folk.

Answer (score 0):

The answer may come a little late but installing libusb (http://www.libusb.org/) worked really fine for me!